# Python - Multiprocessing and database entries

Tags: python, sqlite, multiprocessing

I'm working on a framework for Digital Forensic Investigators to use to compare files with each other for my Master's capstone project.  However, I ran into a bit of a snag...

I'm trying to implement multiprocessing on the comparisons since using a single core seems to be really slow.  The trouble I'm having, however, is when the code goes to enter information into an SQLite database.  It will occasionally get a "Database is locked" error when two cores complete at nearly the same time.

So, simple side of my question, is it unsafe to operate database functions within a multiprocessing environment due to the errors I'm encountering?  If not, is there a method of going about this that is safe and won't result in random errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to have multiple writers access a toy database -- i.e. sqlite -- which is stored in a single file. Using Lock might help, but it's going to kill your multiprocess throughput because of all the waiting-for-the-lock time. In essence, the lock choke point will serialize your program.

Setting up either MySQL or Postgres on almost any platform is straightforward, and there are several excellent Python modules for accessing them. Using one of those will completely eliminate this problem.

**Update for an extended response to comment:**

I always ask clients / students, "What problem are you trying to solve?" I'm assuming that you are not trying to *create* a database system, simply to use one. SQLite3 is fine for a well-defined set of problems, but multiprocess access is *not* one of them. I could veer off into asking what aspect of your project requires multiprocess access, but I'll assume that you have already determined that this is needed. I don't know either your programming skills or your understanding of how a database works, so forgive me if the following is a bit basic.

Normally you need a database (my preference is [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/)), and a Python module that understands all of the fiddly details of how to talk to that database. Then you need to know what it is you want the DBMS to *do* for you. The Good News is that you are hardly the first to go down this path.

The [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/) is full of good stuff. See their page on [Python Drivers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python). Psycopg2 is the category leader and runs on Win/Linux/Mac. Also check out [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), the Python Package Index, for many well-written extensions.

If you want to stay more object-oriented, as opposed to writing straight SQL, you might want to look at an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). This is another category leader that is well-maintained and widely deployed.

The value of using an ORM is that you can (mostly) keep your head in ObjectLand, where most of your problem lives, and not get tangled up in the cognitive dissonance created by object-oriented programming vs. relational database management, which are two *very* different views of the world of data.

If you need more help, email me. My address is in my profile.

Comment: I've never used Lock().  Would I be able to simply wrap the database INSERT statement in Lock(), or do I need to use the Lock() for the entire multiprocessing.process statement?

Comment: Unless using sqlite is absolutely required (why and by whom?), I recommend you not try to reinvent this very complicated wheel (i.e. multi-writer interlock). Use Postgres and get on with your Master's project.

Comment: The main idea for a database was brought up by my advisor, but I'm sure he would be ok with any other database structure.  What concerns me most is that I don't want to have to use any other Python plugins to operate the framework.  Compared to SQLite, how off-putting is the Postgres plugin for Python?  MySQL seemed a bit more difficult because you need to utilize a MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Lock. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes